# Angular 7 compilation error NG8002 can't bind object since it isn't a known property

Tags: html, angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I am doing a test App in angular 7/8. I have compile error `Can't bind 'discounter' since it isn't  a known property of 'paDiscountEditor'`

My html where it shows the error is simple... Here I post all the files needed.

Here is app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ProductComponent } from "./component";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { PaAttrDirective } from "./attr.directive";
import { PaModel } from "./twoway.directive";
import { PaStructureDirective } from "./structure.directive";
import { PaIteratorDirective } from "./iterator.directive";
import { ProductTableComponent } from "./productTable.component";
import { ProductFormComponent } from "./productForm.component";
import { PaToggleView } from "./toggleView.component";
import { PaAddTaxPipe } from "./addTax.pipe";
import { PaCategoryFilterPipe } from "./categoryFilter.pipe";
import { LOCALE_ID } from "@angular/core";
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { PaDiscountDisplayComponent } from "./discountDisplay.component";
import { PaDiscountEditorComponent } from "./discountEditor.component";
registerLocaleData(localeFr);
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductComponent, PaAttrDirective, PaModel, PaStructureDirective, PaIteratorDirective, PaCellColor, PaCellColorSwitcher, ProductTableComponent,
    ProductFormComponent, PaToggleView, PaAddTaxPipe, PaCategoryFilterPipe, PaDiscountDisplayComponent, PaDiscountEditorComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
 // providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "fr-FR" }],
  bootstrap: [ProductComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is discountEditor.component.ts file

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { DiscountService } from "./discount.service";

@Component({
    selector: "paDiscountEditor",
    template: `<div class="form-group">
                   <label>Discount</label>
                   <input [(ngModel)]="discounter.discount" 
                        class="form-control" type="number" />              
               </div>`
})
export class PaDiscountEditorComponent {
 
  constructor(public discounter: DiscountService) { }
}
```

Here is Discount.Service.ts file

```
export class DiscountService {
  private discountValue: number = 10;
  public get discount(): number {
    return this.discountValue;
  }
  public set discount(newValue: number) {
    this.discountValue = newValue || 0;
  }
  public applyDiscount(price: number) {
    return Math.max(price - this.discountValue, 5);
  }
}
```

Here is ProductTable.component.ts file

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Model } from "./repository.model";
import { Product } from "./product.model";
import { DiscountService } from "./discount.service";
@Component({
  selector: "paProductTable",
  templateUrl: "productTable.component.html"
})
export class ProductTableComponent {
  discounter: DiscountService = new DiscountService();
}
```

Here is template.html file

```
<div class="row m-2">
    <div class="col-8 p-2">
        <paProductTable [model]="model"></paProductTable>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is ProductTable.component.html file

```
<paDiscountEditor [discounter]="discounter"></paDiscountEditor>
```

The error I have during Compilation

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed `discounter` as input property here in html

```
<paDiscountEditor [discounter]="discounter"></paDiscountEditor>
```

but your `PaDiscountEditorComponent` component does not have any Input property

you need to add Input property in this component

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { DiscountService } from "./discount.service";

@Component({
    selector: "paDiscountEditor",
    template: `<div class="form-group">
                   <label>Discount</label>
                   <input [(ngModel)]="discounter.discount" 
                        class="form-control" type="number" />              
               </div>`
})
export class PaDiscountEditorComponent {
  @Input() discounter;
  constructor(public discounter: DiscountService) { }
}
```

You can learn more about sharing data between components here :
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: Well, while the reason for the error is what you answered above, your code doesn't compile due to errors: *Duplicate identifier 'discounter'.(2300)*
and *Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'discounter' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'DiscountService'.(2403)*. Also, I'd want ask to OP why do he wants to pass a `class` through `@Input` when he can simply retrieves the instance through DI...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `@Input` property on discounter in `PaDiscountEditorComponent` typescript file